# Converting Java classes to applets

Tags: java, applet

I have four classes of Java in Netbeans IDE and one of them contains the `main` method.  I want to use them as applets.  How do I do that?

Comment: *"i want to use them as applets"*  Bad idea.  Launch them from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Are the main methods currently creating a `Frame` or `JFrame`?

Comment: the main method isnt a frame but it is calling a frame

Comment: Good.  It is a perfect candidate for being launched from a link using JWS.  It will be a lot easier to package and deploy the frame using JWS than convert the code to an applet it embed it in a web page, trust me on that.  Applets are an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend Applet class and need to implement the methods that's required for the Applet class.

Comment: do i extend the Applet class on each java class ?? and do i implement the methods in each class ?

Comment: Not every class only the classes which is gonna be used in the User Interface.

Comment: *"Not every class only the classes which is gonna be used in the User Interface"*  It would be better to state that as '..only the class which ***is*** the main GUI'.  I could post a trivial example where the GUI content (a panel with components in it) is created by a class that extends `Object`.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted to say you desribed it pretty well thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and short answer, you need to either extend the Applet class or JApplet.

The long answer, read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html